# Change Behaviour of Built-in Spark Sql Functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to prevent spark sql functions from nulling values?

For example I have the following dataframe

```
df.show

+--------------------+--------------+------+------------+
|               Title|Year Published|Rating|Length (Min)|
+--------------------+--------------+------+------------+
|      101 Dalmatians|       01/1996|     G|         103|
|101 Dalmatians (A...|          1961|     G|          79|
|101 Dalmations II...|          2003|     G|          70|
```

I want to apply spark sqls `date_format` function to `Year Published` column.

```
val sql = """date_format(`Year Published`, 'MM/yyyy')"""

val df2 = df.withColumn("Year Published", expr(sql))

df2.show

+--------------------+--------------+------+------------+
|               Title|Year Published|Rating|Length (Min)|
+--------------------+--------------+------+------------+
|      101 Dalmatians|          null|     G|         103|
|101 Dalmatians (A...|       01/1961|     G|          79|
|101 Dalmations II...|       01/2003|     G|          70|
```

The first row of the `Year Published` column has been nulled as the original value was in a different date format than the other dates.

This behaviour is not unique to `date_format` for example `format_number` will null non-numeric types.

With my dataset I expect different date formats and dirty data with unparseable values. I have a use case where if the value of a cell cannot be formatted then I want to return the current value as opposed to null.

Is there a way to make spark use the original value in `df` instead of null if the function for `df2` cannot be applied correctly?

**What I've tried**

I've looked at wrapping Expressions in `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions` but could not see a way to replace the existing functions.

The only working solution I could find is creating my own `date_format` and registering it as a udf but this isn't practical for all functions. I'm looking for a solution that will never return null if the input to a function is non-null or an automated way to wrap all existing spark functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use the `coalesce` function for your purposes:

```
coalesce(date_format(`Year Published`, 'MM/yyyy'), `Year Published`)
```